# Error while visiting the site with www

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services, cname

I am getting a proxy error while visiting my site with `www`.fuitter.com.

I recently added www to the cname in the route53.

[image]

Comment: If my memory serves me correct, an IP address isn't valid in a `cname`. It should be used as an alias to a DNS. Try changing the IP to the dns without the subdomain.

Comment: Pretty much. that. You should have posted that as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add another A record for www.fuitter.com pointing to 52.88.43.104.

Also, change your TTL to 1 minute and use the site www.whatsmydns.net to see how your changes are propagating throughout Global DNS servers to help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Alternately replace the IP address with fuitter.com.